# IE will not display generated PDF in browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer, pdf

I've tried many things to get this to work, if I use

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", newFileInfo.Name));
```

instead of

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("inline; filename={0}", newFileInfo.Name));
```

It works, but I need this to display in the browser window to work properly. The inline view works properly in Chrome. I've tried using Response.BinaryWrite and Response.WriteFile  and it made no difference.

I'm using Internet Explorer 9.

Here is my code:

```
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ClearHeaders();
    Response.ClearContent();

    Response.Buffer = true;

    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "public");
    Response.AddHeader("expires", "0");
    Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    string filePath = Request["file"];
    string signatureFile = Request["SignatureImage"];
    double xPos = Convert.ToDouble(Request["X-Pos"]);
    double yPos = Convert.ToDouble(Request["Y-Pos"]);
    double scale = Convert.ToDouble(Request["Scale"]);

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filePath))
    {
        try
        {                
            string newFile = PDFTools.SignPDF(filePath, signatureFile, xPos, yPos, scale, tempDirectory);
            var newFileInfo = new FileInfo(newFile);
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("inline; filename={0}", newFileInfo.Name));
            Response.AddHeader("content-length", newFileInfo.Length.ToString());

            Response.TransmitFile(newFile);
            Response.Flush();
            Response.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
            Debug.WriteLine("at " + ex.StackTrace);
        }
        finally
        {
            Response.End();
        }
    }
```

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chrome has a built-in PDF viewer, but Internet Explorer does not.  Do you have an external PDF viewer (i.e., Adobe Acrobat or Adobe Reader) installed and configured for web view?

Sorry, no rep, can't post comments.

Comment: This fixed my issue, I had a third party pdf viewer installed, uninstalled it and installed the latest adobe reader.

Comment: @kbolino, I looked at lots of post, but finally your solution worked for me. Thanks.